# Intermittent "No leaderboards for this game" error

Tags: android, google-play-services

I am using google play services api for my game.
I am getting intermittent connection issues - for both leaderboard and achievements activity.

The problem is, they are completely random (atleast apparently).
One minute they show up correctly, next minute they simply throw me a

`"No Leaderboards for this game"`
or

```
"No achievements for this game"
```

message on the exactly same apk.

Is anyone else facing the same issue? Am I missing something in the setup?


Note:I have not uploaded the game to google play. I am installing the correctly signed apk by the adb command prompt and checking things out.